# How to get object uint8clampedarray inside a foreach?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, image-manipulation

Here is my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("viewport"); // HTMLCanvasElement
var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); // CanvasRenderingContext2D
var image = new Image();
image.src = "images/a.png";
image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    newFunction();

};

function newFunction()
{
    var imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;
    var imageWidth = image.naturalWidth;

    var data=[];
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
    var data = imageData.data;

    alert(data);

 }
```

This code doesn't gives me the elements of the array.Instead of that it gives [object uint8clampedarray] as the alert message.

Comment: `alert` is not a debugging tool

Comment: What do you mean by not a debugging tool. How can I get the elements inside object uint8clampedarray ?

Comment: I mean that `alert` is not the right tool for inspecting things like objects and arrays, you'd use the console for that.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I use the uint8clampedarray inside forEach() function. It gives an error called 'Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function'

Comment: uint8clampedarrays don't have regular array methods like forEach

Comment: So,how can i loop through the elements in  
uint8clampedarrays?

Comment: `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate typed arrays using a loop as they currently don't come with a `forEach` method:

```
var data = imageData.data;
var i, length = data.length;

for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // data[i]
}
```

There is a proposal to implement an iterator for ES6 in which case you could do:

```
var iteratorArray = data[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iteratorArray.next().value);
```

or a simpler loop doing:

```
for (let v of data) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

But again, these two latter are not yet commonly available.